# Remove Windows Firewall Rule (Exception) using Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, exception, firewall, rule

I am trying to manage firewall rules (exceptions) on Windows 7 using Delphi XE3. I found a very interesting code for adding a rule to Windows firewall, but nothing about deleting (removing) it. Please, can someone help?

Here is the code for adding the rule:

```
procedure AddExceptToFirewall(const Caption, AppPath: String);
// Uses ComObj
const
  NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2;
  NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC  = 4;
  NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP  = 6;
  NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW     = 1;
var
  Profile: Integer;
  Policy2: OleVariant;
  RObject: OleVariant;
  NewRule: OleVariant;
begin
  Profile := NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE OR NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
  Policy2 := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RObject := Policy2.Rules;
  NewRule := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');
  NewRule.Name        := Caption;
  NewRule.Description := Caption;
  NewRule.ApplicationName := AppPath;
  NewRule.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
  NewRule.Enabled := True;
  NewRule.Grouping := '';
  NewRule.Profiles := Profile;
  NewRule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
  RObject.Add(NewRule);
end;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply call [INetFWRules.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/netfw/nf-netfw-inetfwrules-remove), passing in the name of the rule. The name is the same name you used when creating it (`RObject.Name` in the code you've provided above).

```
// Note: Normal COM exception handling should be used. Omitted for clarity.

procedure RemoveExceptFromFirewall(const RuleName: String);
const
  NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2;
  NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC  = 4;
var
  Profile: Integer;
  Policy2: OleVariant;
  RObject: OleVariant;
begin
  Profile := NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE OR NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
  Policy2 := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RObject := Policy2.Rules;
  RObject.Remove(RuleName);
end;
```

There's almost nothing provided in the linked documentation, BTW. I provided the link only for reference.

Comment: @Paruba, you should really consider importing type library instead of copying late-binding code off the internet. Also, you should check `HRESULT` from method call. Both suggestions could save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: FYI, the TypeLibrary for the Firewall API is in `%WINDIR%\System32\FirewallAPI.dll`.

Comment: This has the disadvantage that if you have multiple rules with the same name, it will remove all of them. Not nice.

Comment: In my tests in Win10 it only remove the first entry in the list.
Has the work flow been changed?